# Implementing a text slider or "slideshow" with AJAX or JQuery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I am trying to find a nice way to implement a text slider (examples: News feed or testimonials) with the AJAX control toolkit and/or JQuery that does the following:

- "Slide" (or fade) every few seconds to the next block of text
- The text blocks cannot be static, as there can be hundreds/thousands of them.  Most likely will need to call a .NET web service to return a random block of text.
- This will reside within a .NET User Control and will be included on many different pages

We have done JQuery sliders (both images and text) over and over again, but only within a specific set of HTML blocks that are output to the page.  This time around, we need to dynamically pull (using javascript/jquery) a random text feed from a web service instead of generating all 1000 of the div or list blocks for each "feed" since it would run VERY slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a solution:

We simply created the user control as an AJAX-enabled UC (added the Update panel).  I then added an asp:Timer to the page.  Every page_load (or Tick event if we wanted), we pull a random text block from the database.  No fade or slide effects, but I'm content with the result.